# Converting Curl to C# with RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, rest, curl, restsharp

I'm trying to convert this curl command to C# using RestSharp, and I'm having problems specifically with the data parameter (token and uri variables have been replaced w/dummy values for this example):

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'UserToken: usertoken' --header 'AppToken: apptoken' -d '[{"individualRecordNumber":"foo","score":"bar"}]' 'apiEndpoint'
```

I've been able to successfully do several GET requests within this same API, so I'm good with the overall request format and headers, I'm just having issues figuring out how to format the data and where to append it.  Here's the rest of the request without the data:

```
var client = new RestClient(apiEndpoint);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("usertoken", usertoken);
request.AddHeader("apptoken", apptoken);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I've tried using both AddParameter and AddJsonBody with various combinations of serialized and unserialized versions of the data.

Example of building data directly as string:

```
string examInfo = @"[{""individualRecordNumber"":""foo"",""score"":""bar""}]";
```

Example of building data as object:

```
object[] arrayObj = new object[1];
arrayObj[0] = new { individualRecordNumber = "foo", score = "bar" };
```

This is for a project with an extremely tight turnaround, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: GET requests don't have a body, all the content goes in the request as query parameters.  POST requests have a body.

Comment: Jawad - the error message was that I need to send at least one exam score

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a Post, to "wire in" the Post-Body, AddParameter has this overload

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "mybody", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

or , in your case

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", examInfo, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

but maybe better (if you have  later version)

```
request.AddJsonBody(new { A = "foo", B = "bar" });
```

And the initial constructor: (which you seem to have, but making sure to note it for future readers)

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
```

More full example:

```
var client = new RestClient("https:blahblahblah");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

/* option1 */
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{mybody:'yes'}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

/* OR option 2 */
request.AddJsonBody(new { A = "foo", B = "bar" });

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Fixed an issue with missing ""application/json",  in AddParameter

Comment: Thanks so much!  I had tried both of these formats with the AddParameter and AddJsonBody before, but it turns out there was another issue with the data I was sending.  The system that provides these API calls stores user records with both a string ID (record number) and a GUID ID.  Some of the API calls use the GUID, but it looks like this one needs the shorter string number specifically, and once I switched to that the AddJsonBody code worked as expected.